# Copy-activity from Blob Storage-Account to CosmosDb is very slow

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

#### Situation:

I'm using the **copy-activity** from **azure-data-factory** to copy one json-file with **500 MB** from a **storage-account-blob to CosmosDB** and from **CosmosDb to a storage-Account-blob**

The AzureBlobStorageLinkedService is configured with a **SAS-Token**.

#### Times:

CosmosDb to a storage-Account-blob: **4 minutes**

Storage-account-blob to CosmosDB: **2 hours - over 7 hours (timeout)**

#### CosmosDB:

Before copy-activity will be started, an empty collection with **20.000 RU/s** will be created. I looked at the metrics of CosmosDB and it is really bored. There are only a few 429 errors. We have "default indexing-configuration" and a partitionKey. This means that we have data with several partitionKeys from several partitionKey-ranges (partitions)

#### Data:

In the json-file there are **48.000** json-objects. Some are **small** and some can have **200 KB**.

#### Tries:

I tried with different WriteBatchSizes:

```
5: 2 hours

100: 2 hours

10.000: 7 hours (timeout)
```

I tried it with same/different regions => no difference

I tried it with smaller files => they are much faster (500 KB/s instead of 50 KB/s)

#### Question:

Why it is so slowly?
Is the file with 500 MB too large?

Comment: Are they in different regions? Different resource groups?

Comment: There's really not enough detail to diagnose this. For instance: how did you partition your data? The RU that you allocate is divided up across the underlying physical partitions; if all of your data in a single blob is in a single logical partition (which then maps to a single physical partition), you are only using a fraction of your 20K RU (my guess is around 4K available, since you likely have a default of 5 physical partitions). Also: are you indexing all properties? If so, you'll burn more RU on writes than if you have a custom index policy. Please edit to clarify. But... a very broad q.

Comment: @MaviDomates - There's no correlation of performance related to resource groups, since resource groups are merely  a logical construct for grouping, permissions, etc. And location of resource groups have nothing to do with the region of the services themselves.

Comment: You might want to look at your Cosmos DB metrics to see if there was any throttling taking place during the data move.

Comment: I tried it with same/different regions => no difference.

CosmosDB:
Yes I looked at the metrics of CosmosDB and it is really bored. There are only a few 429 errors. We have "default indexing-configuration" and a partitionKey. This means that we have data with several partitionKeys from several partitionKey-ranges (partitions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with very high throughput-values and it worked fine:

```
1.000.000 RU/s: 9 Minuten ✔
100.000 RU/s: 15 Minuten ✔
```

But I have to think on scaling down after data-transfer ist complete, because of costs!!!